# Small vertical spacing glitch

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, vertical-spacing

I'm having a small vertical spacing issue with the following fraction:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \frac{p_x^2}{2 m} \frac{p_y^2}{2 m} \frac{p_{\smash{y}}^2}{2 m}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview of the issue:

[image]

As you can see, the second "p" symbol is vertically shifted a bit (and also its "2"), because of the "y" index.  I don't like that.  I want to fix all the "p" and "2" at the exact same height.  Smashing the offending "y" solves the issue, but then the "y" almost hit the horizontal bar, which is ugly.  So is there a way to rise a bit the "y" while keeping the "p" and "2" at the same height?

Comment: \vphantom{y}x maybe?

Comment: @mickep, your suggestion would rise the first "p", which isn't desirable.  I need to fix the second "p".

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent math typography? The equations is centered on the fractional line. If you implement your suggestion what would happen, if you only have a `p` with no subscript?

Comment: @yannisl, I want all the "p" to stay on their line, with or without any subscript.  The "y" index is the only issue here.  I just want to rise it a bit, so its "p" stays the same as the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \frac{p_x^2}{2 m}
        \frac{p_{\raisebox{2.5pt}{$\smash{_y}$}}^2}{2 m}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I see, to align the subscripts `x` and `y` in the fractions, you can use the `subdepth` package along with the `\smash[b]` command. Here's how you can adjust your equation:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subdepth} % for adjusting subscript depth

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{p_x^{\smash[b]{2}}}{2 m}, \frac{p_y^{\smash[b]{2}}}{2 m} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

By using `\smash[b]{}` around the superscripts, you prevent them from affecting the line spacing, ensuring that the subscripts `x` and `y` are aligned vertically. The `subdepth` package adjusts the subscript depth to avoid uneven vertical spacing.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In LuaTeX (i.e. in OpTeX too) you can control the numerator default distance from the fraction rule by the `\Umathfractionnumup` LuaTeX primitive:

```
\Umathfractionnumup\textstyle=.6em
\Umathfractionnumup\displaystyle=.78em

${p_x\over 2m}, {p_y\over 2m}$

$$
  {p_x\over 2m}, {p_y\over 2m}
$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd outright reject raising the *y*.

Here's a comparison between your `\smash` method and my method of equalizing the subscripts.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixcmex}% don't forget this if you use lmodern

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\arule}{\rlap{\color{red}\smash{\vrule width 1cm depth0.1pt height 0pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\frac{\arule p_x^{\arule 2}}{2 m} \frac{p_{\smash{y}}^2}{2 m}
&\qquad&
\frac{p_x^{2}}{2 m} \frac{p_{\smash{y}}^2}{2 m}
\\
&\frac{\arule p_{\mathstrut x}^{\arule 2}}{2 m} \frac{p_{\mathstrut y}^2}{2 m}
&&
\frac{p_{\mathstrut x}^{2}}{2 m} \frac{p_{\mathstrut y}^2}{2 m}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also try `\smash[t]{\mathstrut}`, exploiting the fact that neither letter has ascenders.